# XML Evaluate WrongDocumentError on Firefox an IE

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox

I did a simple XML Request and everything works fine in Chrome, Safari etc. But I get following error in firefox and IE:

> WrongDocumentError: Node cannot be used in a document other than the one in which it was created

The line the message is referring to is this:

```
var x = document.evaluate(path, xml.responseXML.documentElement, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue;
```

Here is the complete function:

```
function parseXMLID(xml, id) {

    /* define product Array */
    var productInfo = [];   
    var serialNumber = id;

    /* set path for parse xml */
    var path = '//productid[text()="' + serialNumber + '"]/..';

    /* parse xml for path */
    var x = document.evaluate(path, xml.responseXML.documentElement, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue;
}
```

Can you see what I did wrong here?

Hope you can help me,
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invoke `evaluate` method on the document you're searching:

```
xml.responseXML.evaluate(path, xml.responseXML.documentElement, null, 9, null)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is working, but why was it working in chrome then?

Comment: The [DOM Level 3 XPath spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-XPath-20040226/DOM3-XPath.html#xpath-XPathEvaluator-evaluate) states: *If the XPathEvaluator was obtained by casting the Document then [the context node] must be owned by the same document.* It seems that Chrome doesn't enforce this requirement which could be considered a bug.